# Regex extract numbers of all lengths

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract numbers of length 3 to 5 from a long string of text. Let me explain

Say there is a string like this `123456` and I want to extract all the number that are between length 3 and 5 output would be

```
123
234
345
456
1234
2345
3456
12345
23456
```

I can run multiple regex that individually find the lengths but there might be a better way to do that than what I am doing.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTestHarness {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String data = "123456";

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}").matcher(data);

        // m = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}").matcher(data);
        // m = Pattern.compile("\\d{5}").matcher(data);

        int position = 0;

        while (m.find(position++)) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Premature Optimization Idea - I can match everything to 5 and then run smaller length matchers on the result of those. That way I cut down on reading the data over and over which in my case is an external source.

Comment: A regular expression can find any contiguous sequence of digits, but then you'd have to look through that, extracting every substring.

Comment: @p.s.w.g It's not quite that simple, because a substring can be split across two matches.

Comment: @DavidWallace What I mean is, find any sequence of 3 or more digits, and then loop through that sequence extracting every substring of length 3, 4, and 5.

Comment: Why don't you extract numbers 5 digits or more and calculate permutations afterwards?

Comment: This looks a lot harder with regex; do you really need to use it?

Comment: @p.s.w.g Sorry, you're right, I withdraw my earlier comment.  But you should turn that into an answer, using `"\\d+"` and `substring`.  I'll upvote it if you do it correctly.

Comment: @fge - That's exactly what I suggested in my Optimization Idea. So that's on the plate.

Comment: @Quincunx - Yes, I have a working solution that doesn't use regex. I was looking for something concise. Given that it doesn't get too complicated for the next dev.

Comment: @DarK Don't default to regex for concise code. With complicated things like this, it can create bigger code or code that runs slower. Also, it is important to remember that many people don't understand regex (shame on them, regex is beautiful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a single regex. Just globally find.
Print capture groups 1,2,3 if thier lengths are greater than 0

```
 #  "(?=(\\d{3}))(?=(\\d{4}))?(?=(\\d{5}))?"

 (?=
      ( \d{3} )         # (1)
 )
 (?=
      ( \d{4} )         # (2)
 )?
 (?=
      ( \d{5} )         # (3)
 )?
```

Perl test case

```
while ( '123456' =~ /(?=(\d{3}))(?=(\d{4}))?(?=(\d{5}))?/g )
{
     print "$1\n";
     if ( length ($2) ) {
         print "$2\n";
     }
     if ( length ($3) ) {
         print "$3\n";
     }
}
```

Output >>

```
123
1234
12345
234
2345
23456
345
3456
456
```

Comment: The first time I've ever upvoted an answer in Perl to a question in Java.

Comment: I always include simple Perl test cases, but the regex's solutions are always strictly in the OP's tagged lang. Thank you.

Comment: @sln - I am leaning towards this regex `(((\\d{3})\\d?)\\d?)` .

Comment: It looks like you get duplicates with nested (containing) capture groups.

Comment: Yes, but I can easily filter that out. I don't have understanding of performance tradeoff's yet, so cannot comment on that. Although performance is not an issue in my case, it would be good to know the internals.

Answer (score 2):

This looks a lot harder with regex. If you don't need to use it, loop through each one of the starting positions and extract the numbers:

```
// If this string is just plain numbers, skip the dataArray and the
// for (String s: dataArray) and replace the s's in the loops with data's

String data = "123456 some other datas 654321";
String[] dataArray = data.split("\\D+");

for (String s: dataArray){
    for (int length = 3; length <= 5; length++){
        for (int index = 0; index <= s.length() - length; index++) {
            int maxIndex = index + length;
            System.out.println(s.substring(index, maxIndex));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
123
234
345
456
1234
2345
3456
12345
23456
654
543
432
321
6543
5432
4321
65432
54321
```

Comment: Where do you test that you're only getting digits?

Comment: @DavidWallace Oh was that required? Let me fix that.

Comment: I thought it was, but maybe I misunderstood the question.  The way I see it, you want to iterate through matches of `"\\d+"` and do exactly what you've done, for each match.

Comment: Which _looks harder_, a single loop regex or, a tripple loop non-regex?

Comment: @sln the triple loop because it is easier to understand. The main advantage IMO is that my way is easier to read because it takes a minute to parse regex.

Comment: You can always use [RegexFormat4](http://www.regexformat.com) to turn compressed regex into formatted expanded regex with a single button clicks. Then put it into your source (useing its Xpanded modifier) or just button click it into compressed output from RXF app. Either way, thats not an issue nowadays.

Comment: Yes, @sln it _is_ an issue.  For most applications, the most important attribute of production software is its maintainability, and that starts with how easy code is to read and understand quickly.  It is _much_ easier to read Quincunx's solution, and know exactly what it's doing, than to understand a pure regular expression solution full of lookaheads and non-matching groups.  sln, if I, in my capacity as a professional programmer, were faced with this as a production problem, I would choose a solution like Quincunx's, not a solution like yours, for no other reason than maintainability.

Comment: I am leaning towards this, easier for people who cannot understand regex. Solution by @sln is picked only because it's correct and uses regex so stays true to the question asked. Thanks!

Comment: I respect everyones opinion about regex (good or bad), as it is at the very least dificult thing to do right at times. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution for 3-5 match only. I am using lookahead to find the overlapping matching from the string. I have used three regex here practically.

```
String text = "123456";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=(\\d\\d\\d))(?=(\\d\\d\\d\\d?))(?=(\\d\\d\\d\\d?\\d?))");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);

// taking out all the captures from the Matcher
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    list.add(m.group(1));
    list.add(m.group(2));
    list.add(m.group(3));
}

// making the list unique using HashSet
list = new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(list));

// printing
for(String s : list){
    System.out.println(s);
}

// output is not sorted, if you want you can sort the List<>
```

Comment: What if the input is `"1234 123"`?  You might actually want duplicates.

Comment: @DavidWallace you mean having space in between?

Comment: @DavidWallace By the way, try to run the code. I have unique checking at the end over the list.

Comment: I did run the code.  You need to remove duplicates because of the way you've done the regular expression.  But you need to NOT remove duplicates in case they're duplicates that are really wanted.  So this answer is never going to work exactly right.  But it's a very clever idea.